# How to copy selected file into folder using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to store/copy file into folder using JavaScript. file is getting from input type file. . 
JavaScript Code -

```
function submitForm(action)
{
    // here I want to do copy file into folder
}
```

HTML Code-

```
<form id="exampleForm" method="post" action=""  enctype="multipart/form-data" >

      <input  type="file" class="upload" name="imagename" id="imagename" />

      <input type="button" name="save_exit"  id="save_exit" onclick="submitForm('add_question_sql.php')" value="Save &amp; Exit"   />
</form>
```

I can not use Submit button for some reason.
So how can I copy a file into folder using JavaScript ?

Comment: Your question is pretty simple and clean. Google will accompany you with this.

Comment: javascript is a client-side language with limited access to the filesystem. iirc you cannot alter the filesystem of the client with javascript; that would be a major security issue. moreover being a client language you don't have access to the filesystem of the server using javascript. you'd better describe your requirement because it looks like this solution you found (javascript to copy files) cannot be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Paulo, this is not a JavaScript topic. On selection of a file and submission of the form, your server-side application will receive the request and will be in a position to receive the uploaded file and store it somewhere on your server.

Comment: Is this possible to send file data/details to ajax file using ajax in submitForm(). Then we use move_uploaded_file() of php in ajax file. ? If this is possible then how ?

Comment: Ah I see. You want the upload to be handled silently, without refreshing the page. Well, yes, files can be uploaded via Ajax. This feature was added in XMLHttpRequest Level 2, which is not supported by some major browsers that are still widely used, notably Internet Explorer 9. But if that's not a problem, here's a great intro to XML 2 including instructions for uploading files: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript is Client-side language . so its not possible using javascript.

U have to use any backend technology. like php, java, node.